# Stack level too deep in recursive method

Tags: ruby, recursion

When I run this code:

```
def binarySearch(key, arr, min, max)
  if max < min  
    return -1
  else
    midpoint = arr[(arr.length-1)/2]
    if midpoint < key
      binarySearch(key, arr, midpoint, max)
    elsif midpoint > key
      binarySearch(key,arr, min, midpoint)
    else
      return midpoint
    end
  end
end

arr = [0,1,2,3,6,77,23,1133,44,144,232,112]
arr.sort!
binarySearch(144, arr, arr.min, arr.max)
```

I get a stack level too deep error:

```
tree.rb:15:in `binarySearch': stack level too deep (SystemStackError)
from tree.rb:15:in `binarySearch'
...
```

Is there a reason why it cannot find the return statement when the right block is reached? Someone suggested to define `initialize` with a default of `nil`, then activate it for the first run.

Comment: Which articles told you Ruby just needs a return statement to be alright?

Comment: sorry not a return statement but something to break the conditional in order to force an end to calling the function again

Answer (score 1):

1) ruby does not need a return statement - but a recursive algorithm always does. However, this is NOT your problem

2)
    midpoint = arr[(arr.length-1)/2]

this value never changes - every time you call binarySearch, you will always get the same value for midpoint... over and over and over... forever.... which is why you are getting the Stack overflow.

because no matter how deep into the stack you go, midpoint will always be either < or > key... no matter what you do.

You need to do something different each time in order for something to change.

Note: when you call binarySearch from within binarySearch - you are changing the min/max values, but not the way you are calculating the midpoint... think about that.

Comment: Thank you! I did not notice that. Is it bad practice to just delete the items of an array for the sake of a search if i just slice off the end that I am not interested in searching? (assuming my sort was correct). I am just practicing for interviews and do not know if that is odd or not....

the local scope of the array would only change right and outside I could still have the entire array?

Comment: use slice instead of delete and you'll be on the right track :) Yep - it'll all be local.

Answer (score 0):

The array needs to get smaller each time you recurse. You are passing the full array every time instead of just the front half or just the back half.

Answer (score 0):

1) As others pointed out, you should calculate the midpoint between the current values of max and min rather than based on the array length, which doesn't change.

2) You're comparing the midpoint to the key-value.  Change that to a comparison of the array value at the midpoint vs the key-value, e.g. `if arr[midpoint] < key`, etc.

3) Kick off the search with min and max set to 0 and `arr. length - 1`, respectively, rather than `arr.min` and `arr.max`.